# How do I create a deployment from a package in Blob Storage in Azure preview portal?

Tags: azure

In the previous Silverlight Azure Management portal it was possible to "browse storage" and select a service package and the service configuration from Blob Storage:

[image: old portal]

and that was very convenient.

Now in the "preview" new portal the equivalent dialog looks like this:

[image: new portal]

Looks like the only option now is uploading the file directly from my computer.

How do I create or update a deployment from files in Blob Storage now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is available just yet in the new portal. You can always go to the old portal from the newer one and use the feature from there. There are still a number of things that the new portal will not do (e.g. SQL Azure Management, Managing Co-admins etc. to name a few) and for those, you would need to go to the old portal.

Hope this helps.